# Платный хостинг

Tags: joomla, html, хостинг

Доброго всем времени суток, подскажите, пожалуйста, украинские платные хостинги, на которых можна купить домен com.ua. Только, что б этот хостинг был проверен людьми. Дело в том, что я раньше пользовался бесплатными, пока не настало время купить домен. Заранее благодарин!

Answer (score 2):

Требования очень расплывчатые, непонятно для чего нужен хостинг, если просто сайт визитка, то практически любой подойдет, например, nic.ua, или uh.ua. Вообще же лучше купить домен отдельно на любом из симпатичных регистраторов, а хостинг выбирать уже из технических требований.

Answer (score 0):

host.com.ua, colocall.netС обоими работаю не один год, отличный хостинг.